# Add two PWM to DC inputs

Tags: voltage, circuit-design

I have an Arduino Mega and I'm following this [PWM to Analog-Output](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Analog-Output) page to create a constant DC output.

[image: PWM to DC]

If the max output for the PWM 5 volts, is there a way to put two of these circuits in series to make a DC out that is able to go from 0->10 Volts? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: If you have a single 5V power supply for these circuits? No.

Comment: Agreed. You would need to use a summing amplifier powered from, probably, a 12 V supply. Search for "non-inverting op-amp summing amplifier".

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: I'm not sure if your comment was to me or OP. I read the question as "*I have two filtered PWM outputs that I want to add to generate a maximum range of 0 - 10 V.*" The question is poorly worded.

Comment: @Transistor: Or, perhaps the real question is: "How can I use some number of PWMs output generate a DC output that is adjustable from 0 to 10V?", in which case a single PWM output and a non-inverting amplifier with a gain of 2 powered by a 12V supply would be sufficient.

Comment: @Transistor is correct in his interpretation. I have a situation where my two filtered outputs go from 0 to 5V in N steps. I was trying to figure out a way that I could combine the outputs to create a single DC out with 2N steps (presumably adding them to a range of 0 to 10V)

Comment: But the others may be on the right track too. Are your two PWM sources generated by the same micro and can you program it? If so you could average the two PWMs internally, put them out on one pin and use an op-amp with a gain of two. If either of those is false then my suggestion would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Transistor is correct in his interpretation. I have a situation where my two filtered outputs go from 0 to 5V in N steps. I was trying to figure out a way that I could combine the outputs to create a single DC out with 2N steps (presumably adding them to a range of 0 to 10V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbnKfp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A non-inverting summing amplifier.*

How it works:

- The voltage on OA1+ input will be \$ \frac {PWM1 + PWM2}{2} \$.
- The gain of the non-inverting amplifier is \$ 1 + \frac {R5}{R3} = 2 \$.
- Output will be \$ PWM1 + PWM2 \$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make R3 double or 1/2 of R4? You would want one PWM to be double the weight of the other PWM to have a truly 2N dynamic range.

Comment: I think you're thinking of an R / 2R kind of binary added. It's not applicable in this case. If PWM1 and PWM2 can be any value between 0 and 100, say, then the sum can be any integer value between 0 and 200. The resolution doubles. Your scheme would have 100 full steps and 100 half steps with the sum giving 0 to 150 in half-step resolution. Better resolution but not the required output and not the simple sum of two PWMs as requested.

Comment: If I understand correctly, using Transistor's numbers @VincePatron 's solution would provide 300 steps as opposed to the 200 steps my requested solution provided. Does that mean, given two PMW's with N steps each, I could make R3 = R4/N and create an 2 digit N-nary output?

Comment: I'm kind of losing track at this stage. Maybe you could but I suspect you'd find that resistor tolerances start to swamp any accuracy gains. Would it not be better to dither the PWM outputs for increased accuracy? e.g., for 75.25% you output 75% for three periods and 76% for one. Repeat.

Comment: Perhaps, this is really my first electrical engineering project so [I'm still figuring out feasibility](https://xkcd.com/1425/). I now know that, if I made sure my minor step size was twice my resistor's accuracy, I am able to get many more steps than the 2N I originally thought possible.

Comment: Is that what your question was really about?